# navbar wont center with the regular css settings

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center, navbar

so i'm trying to center a navbar,
i tried:

```
.navbar-nav {
display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-default {
text-align: center; 
}
```

But no luck, it only centers the dropdown content... tried some other suggestions i found here on stack overflow but still was not able to center it.

I'm using bootstrap.css & a flat-ui.css, maybe it has to do with it.
fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/MikeStardust/xZ6YM/
If something is missing on the fiddle please check the temp website at: http://tf2.site40.net

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with `container`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/xZ6YM/1/)**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar navbar-default">         
            //stuff
</div>    
</div>
```

Update: If you want the outer width to be full width, you can wrap it with `header` . Thanks @kristjanReinhold

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/xZ6YM/4/)**

```
<header class="navbar">
<div class="container">
//stuff
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: <!-- Docs master nav -->
    <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

Comment: @kristjanreinhold its not centered but its better than it was

Comment: @MikeStardust Its actually center, you feel it like because your menu is floated to left.

Comment: i've trieed the updated one and the result is the same, but with a larger navbar in weight

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block;` only makes a div as wide its content, to center, you must specify the margins too!!

```
.navbar-nav {
   display: inline-block;
   margin:0 auto; /* this will center the div*/
}
```

Comment: The result is the same, the dropdown contents are centered, but the navbar isnt

Comment: Why would you even ruin twitter's bootstrap working component. Thats the point of it, easy to use.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold : because TBS, gives a base of work and design...but sometimes, layout require more than existing classes...simple!! :)

Comment: Sometimes, but not in this case.

Comment: @MikeStardust : your fiddle doesnt show anything under `ul` tag even after adding `border:1px solid #000;`....mind updating it http://jsfiddle.net/xZ6YM/3/ so that we have something to work on it!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor thats why i added a temp website, so you guys can check all the resources

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it into a `<div class="container">`